# How can assign multiple selected values to the text field using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a dynamic text field value from angularjs post request. Based on the response text field will increase or decrease. I want to edit that value from multiple selected options field.

Html code given below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="opt in myData">
     <td>
        <input type="text" id="opt{{$index + 1}}" name="option{{$index + 1}}"   ng-model="opt.options" ng-value="opt.options"  />
     </td>
     </tr>
```

Multiple select options are here, based on the selection I want to change the text field value

Html code for first selection given below

```
<select ng-model="garden" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Flowers</option>
  <option>Shrubs</option>
  <option>Trees</option>
  <option>Bushes</option>
  <option>Grass</option>
  <option>Dirt</option>
</select>
```

Second Selection Html code given below

```
<select ng-model="country" multiple="multiple">
  <option>USA</option>
  <option>UK</option>
  <option>USR</option>
</select>
```

Please any one help I'm new in Angularjs. Thanks for all

Comment: I think you could make the question clearer. It is not clear how text fields in `ng-repeat` relate to the drop-down lists. Which text field did you refer to and how should it be updated?

Comment: From ng-repeat I got three text field with value. I want to edit that value using selection field.

Comment: when i click option 'USA' I want to edit that text field value as USA in the first text field. Next I click 'Trees' I want two text field first as USA and second text field as 'Trees'

Comment: How do you decide which of the 3 text fields to update? Since it is multiple select, what happens when you click 'Trees' and 'Dirt'? You could add `ng-change` directive to `select` and update `myData` accordingly.

Comment: using Jquery I can do demo https://jsfiddle.net/mh7Lvpug/1/ is it possible for  angularjs ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/nxjtL7wa/ ?

Comment: ya good work but. I want each value in each text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `ng-change` directive to select and update `myData` accordingly in controller.

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="opt in myData">
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="{{opt.id}}" name="{{opt.id}}" value="{{opt.value}}" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<select ng-model="country" multiple="multiple" ng-change="selectChange(country)">
  <option>USA</option>
  <option>UK</option>
  <option>USR</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="garden" multiple="multiple" ng-change="selectChange(garden)">
  <option>Flowers</option>
  <option>Shrubs</option>
  <option>Trees</option>
  <option>Bushes</option>
  <option>Grass</option>
  <option>Dirt</option>
</select>
```

`selectChange()` in controller

```
$scope.selectChange = function(val) {
      // selection logic goes here
      $scope.myData = []; // reset selections
      var id = $scope.myData.length;
      angular.forEach(val, function(v, k) { // iterate list and add new selections 
        $scope.myData.push({
          'id': id + k,
          'value': v
        });
      });
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nxjtL7wa/2/

Comment: You're welcome. Probably not exactly what you wanted but should get you started.

Comment: How can i avoid duplicate data entry ?

Comment: Did you take `$scope.myData` out of the function? You can ask a new question on that.

Comment: Did u check that link in chrome browser? it's something wrong but nice work in Mozilla

Comment: That's browser support issue. This should work http://jsfiddle.net/ranru/crukfe1m/